# Find if a number is divisible in a range of numbers

Tags: haskell, recursion

I do want to compare an integer (rstart) with an integer (number) in the following way (C code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){
    int rstart = 15, rend = 25, number = 629;
    while (rstart <= rend){
        rstart++;
        if (number % rstart == 0){
            return number % rstart;
        }
    }   
    return number % rstart;
}
```

Now I do know how to write something like this in c or python but I do have no clue how to do it in Haskell.

I did start out with the following:

```
dividesRange :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool
dividesRange number rstart rend =
```

I do not know how I would implement the while loop from C in Haskell. I know I could use all if statements but that is inefficient in my opinion. Is there an easy way to write this in Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```hs
dividesRange :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool
dividesRange number rstart rend = go rstart where
  go x
    | x > rend = False
    | otherwise = number `rem` x == 0 || go (x+1)
```

How it works:

1. We use a helper function `go`.
2. The base case is when `x` (rstart), is greater than `rend`. In that case we return False.
3. Otherwise we check if the remainder of `number` divided by `x` is zero. If so, we return True and don't recurse further.
4. Otherwise we increase `x` and call `go` again.

Using [`any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) we can rewrite the above as follows:

```hs
dividesRange2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool
dividesRange2 number rstart rend = any (\x -> number `rem` x == 0) [rstart..rend]
```